# Center align and place items beneath one another in Angular Mat-Grid-Tile

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm trying to make a login page using Angular Material. I have some code that is shown below:

```
<mat-grid-list cols="2">
  <mat-grid-tile>
    <div>
      <h1 class="title">Welcome back!</h1>
      <span class="spanText">Please enter your details to get started</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <form>
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
          <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
          <input matInput placeholder="Enter your email" />
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
          <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
          <input matInput placeholder="Enter your password" />
        </mat-form-field>
      </form>
    </div>
  </mat-grid-tile>

  <mat-grid-tile>Image Here</mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

And the CSS:

```
div {
  display: block;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.title {
  font-size: 70px;
}

.spanText {
  color: rgb(102, 98, 100);
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.tileContent {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

The problem that I have is that I am trying to:

1. Center align the items
2. Place the items below one another

However I cannot and any changes that I make seem to make no impact. How can I fix this and make sure that the items that are being placed including the `h1` and `span` are center aligned. Currently, they're being placed one after another in a in-line style.

As of now, they are being shown like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8Nax.jpg

Comment: `align-items: center;` and `justify-content: center;`  works with `display: flex;` on your div element. Change your `display: block;` to `display: flex;`

Comment: I tried it but it is still the same. Please see the image as well I just uploaded as well